# Allow ony specific Email Address Domain to register as customer in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Need to know I can allow only specific domain email addresses to register as customer in Woocommerce.

And then redirect them to a specific page or url.

Also want to know how I can limit woocommerce transaction to be carried out per user. I mean only 5 translations per user should be executed in a time frame of 24 hours.